# Write Conflict mongoose transactions

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, transactions, e-commerce

In my application i am trying to build a route for creating orders the flow should go like this:

```
1- reserve the products for the user
2- empty the user's cart
3- take payment
```

however if one operation fails the database should return to its original state before updating any documents

I'm using mongodb

this is what i tried:

```
export default async function order(userId) {
  const User = mongoose.model('user');
  const Product = mongoose.model('product');
  const Order = mongoose.model('order');

  const session = await mongoose.startSession();

  session.startTransaction();

  try {
    const user = await User.findById(userId).session(session);

    // reserve the product for the user
    const results = await Product.bulkWrite(
      user.cart.map((item) => ({
        updateOne: {
          filter: {
            _id: item.product,
            'combinations.size': item.size,
            'combinations.color': item.color,
            'combinations.qty': { $gte: item.qty },
          },
          update: {
            $inc: { 'combinations.$.qty': -item.qty },
          },
        },
      })),
      { session }
    );

    if (results.nModified !== user.cart.length) {
      throw new Error('Not all products available, transaction aborted');
    }
    // empty user's cart
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, { cart: [] }).session(session);

    // take payment from the user
    const payment = (successed) => {
      if (successed) return { id: 'charge id' };

      throw new Error('payment failed');
    };

    const charge = payment(true);

    const productsInCart = await Product.find({
      _id: { $in: user.cart.map((item) => item.product.toString()) },
    });

    // create the order
    await Order.create([
      {
        user: userId,
        products: user.cart.map((item) => ({
          ...item,
          price: productsInCart.find(
            (product) => product._id.toString() === item.product.toString()
          ).price.curr1,
        })),

        currency: 'curr1',
        status: 'placed',
        chargeId: charge.id,
      },
    ]);

    await session.commitTransaction();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    await session.abortTransaction();
  } finally {
    await session.endSession();
  }
}
```

however when testing it i get this error
[image]

these are my models:
User:

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  cart: [
    {
      product: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'product' },
      color: String,
      size: String,
      qty: Number,
    },
  ],
  orders: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'order' }],
});

model('user', UserSchema);
```

Product

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';

const ProductSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  price: {
    curr1: Number, // price in a region
    curr2: Number, // price in another region
  },
  combinations: [
    {
      size: String,
      color: String,
      qty: Number,
    },
  ],
});

model('product', ProductSchema);
```

Order:

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';

const OrderSchema = new Schema({
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
  products: [
    {
      product: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'product' },
      size: String,
      color: String,
      qty: Number,
      price: Number,
    },
  ],
  currency: String,
  status: String,
  chargeId: String,
});

model('order', OrderSchema);
```

and my test:

```
import async from 'async';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import order from '../src/order.js';

const User = mongoose.model('user');
const Order = mongoose.model('order');
const Product = mongoose.model('product');

describe('Race condition for orders', async () => {
  let products;
  let users;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    products = await Product.insertMany([
      {
        title: 'test product 1',
        price: { curr1: 10, curr2: 10 },
        combinations: [
          {
            size: 'large',
            color: 'black',
            qty: 1,
          },
          {
            size: 'small',
            color: 'red',
            qty: 2,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: 'test product 2',
        price: { curr1: 10, curr2: 10 },
        combinations: [
          {
            size: 'medium',
            color: 'yellow',
            qty: 1,
          },
        ],
      },
    ]);

    users = await User.insertMany([
      {
        email: 'test@test.test',
        cart: products.map((product) => ({
          product: product._id.toString(),
          size: product.combinations[0].size,
          color: product.combinations[0].color,
          qty: 1,
        })),
      },
      {
        email: 'test2@test.test',
        cart: products.map((product) => ({
          product: product._id.toString(),
          size: product.combinations[0].size,
          color: product.combinations[0].color,
          qty: 1,
        })),
      },
    ]);
  });

  it('calls order twice at the same time', async () => {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      async.parallel(
        [
          async () => {
            await order(users[0]._id.toString());
          },
          async () => {
            await order(users[1]._id.toString());
          },
        ],
        (err, res) => {
          if (err) return reject(err);

          resolve(res);
        }
      )
    );

    console.log(await Order.find({}));
  });
});
```